# Laravel basic routing returns 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've recently started learning Laravel but there is one problem which I don't know why it occurs. My current Laravel project is located at `wamp/www/codebright`. When I access `localhost/codebright/public` I see the welcome page to Laravel.

When I create a simple routing:

```
Route::get('my/page', function()
{
    return "Harro world";
});
```

and trying to access:
`localhost/codebright/public/my/page` it returns with 404 error, not even with Laravel error. I've also tried to access: `localhost/codebright/my/page` and still.

However, if I type in CMD `php artisan serve` and open a server on 8000 port and then access: 
`localhost:8000/my/page` it works just fine. I would like to know why my first method without the `artisan` command didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

## Note

It seems like that if you have XAMPP installed, none of the problems mentioned above and in the answer comment section are occurring. Basically, if you are using XAMPP, you most likely won't get any error and the program will work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to do what you want but if you're not using `artisan serve` you must have a webserver set up correctly. From your original post you obviously have a webserver set up as you get the welcome page, but it looks to me like one of the following:

- You don't have the `.htaccess` file in place
- Your base vhost (or Apache config if not using a vhost) on your web server setup does not `AllowOverride All` (which is required to allow `.htaccess` files to work)
- You don't have `mod_rewrite` turned on

You should check these out. As a minimum, Laravel requires a way to turn URIs that don't exist as real files (`my/page`) into something it can fake a page for. This pretty much requires the use of `mod_rewrite` and an `.htaccess` file to specify the rules.

---

Explanation of the difference between using Apache and `artisan serve`: `artisan serve` does not use a 'dumb' webserver like Apache and instead uses a webserver built into PHP which has knowledge of how to handle 'non-existing' URIs that you browse to, which is why you don't need `mod_rewrite` and the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Okay, that explains the problem. Any suggestion? What should I use? `php artisan serve` or access directly into my `public` folder. Please also refer to the host that my web application will finally be in. What I mean is that I can't run `php artisan serve` on my website when it's stored in my host company so I will have to access the `public` directory, right? How do I fix my files so it will work?

Comment: The vast majority of hosting providers will have `mod_rewrite` installed *and* `AllowOverride All` for your vhost, allowing you to use `.htaccess` files. My point being that this is such a common requirement for PHP applications as a whole (Laravel is in no way special here, and these requirements aren't crazy) that they all support it - and if they don't you need a new host.

Comment: Locally you can do what you want, though I'd suggest trying to set your Apache environment up properly (to save on having to do the serve thing every time you work on the site) - it may just be a case of doing `sudo a2enmod rewrite` on your command line, and then checking that `AllowOverride All` is set in your Apache configuration.

Comment: Even when I change my `apache/conf/httpd.conf` file to: `<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>` I still cant do things like `localhost/codebright/public/my/page`.
In my `public` directory, this is my .htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/zMeyJVnH

Comment: And do you definitely have `mod_rewrite` enabled? It doesn't come enabled on Apache by default with a lot of distributions, but it does come bundled, so just needs enabling.

Comment: I've enabled mode_rewrite. Now i get Laravel error instead of 404 error. The error says: `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException` I get that error for every route I'm trying to access other than `/` Any idea?

Comment: You might find you need to set RewriteBase in the `.htaccess` file. I don't but sometimes people do. Try that: `RewriteBase /codebright/public/`

Comment: Thanks alex! that was it. I have no idea what `RewriteBase /codebright/public/` does (I would like to know if you can) but it solves the issue

Comment: It's a bit of a hack (and need to be taken out of the code when it's on the production server) that kinda means "pretend all paths I refer to in this rewrite section have the following prepended". So in your case, it makes it so that Apache can recognise `/codebright/public/my/path` as `/my/path` by ignoring the RewriteBase value part of the URI and similarly, when rewriting to `index.php` it knows that it should actually be `/codebright/public/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created virtual host for your laravel project?

If no here is how to create virtual host in window

Step 1: Open apache conf file

```
apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Add below code in last line.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mark-thomas.loc
    DocumentRoot E:\wamp\www\codebright\public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory E:\wamp\www\codebright\public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`E:\wamp\www\codebright\public` is your laravel app path, you can replace it with your folder path.

Step 2:
Open-> Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Add your ip address in list of IP address

192.168.1.231       www.laravel.loc

Restart your apache server hit `http://www.laravel.loc/my/page`. Now you will see your message!

Comment: Hey! What's the difference between your solution and `php artisan serve`? They both create a webserver which I can work on. Yours creates `http://www.laravel.loc` and the other `localhost:8000`. I was simply asking if its possible to make it work from the `public` directory so I can type `localhost/codebright/public/my/page` rather than setting the virtual host and type `localhost:8000/my/page`. Thanks!